# How do you access the another child element with Angular Directive?

Tags: html, angular, dom, directive, angular12

I am using Angular directive to manipulate DOM.

For E.g.
HTML:

```
<div id="someHeadWrapper" appSomeDirective>
  <div id="someSecondWrapper">Whatever...</div>
  <btn id="someBtn" #btn>ClickMe</btn>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSomeDirective]'
})

contructor(private el:ElementRef){
 console.log(el.nativeElement)
}
```

With this directive I have access of "someHeadWrapper". But I want to manipulate elements with id="someSecondWrapper" and id="someBtn".

I can access this with
`this.el.nativeElement.children` which is giving me array of children and that is doing job for me. But its not legit way. If someone changes HTML code after me, He must have to track this changes in directive.

If anyone can help.

Angular version : 12

Comment: What is your purpose for changing the id? Id is unique identifier.

Comment: I guess you didnt get my question. Requirement is not changing id, Requirement is accessing any other element other than where directive is used. I want to change style of child elements, But not sure legit way to access them.

Comment: Rephrased sentence for you.